# Creating lambda expression in class using members

Tags: c++, class, lambda, member

I am trying to create a class member function which returns a lambda expression, based on the class members. For simplification I created this example code.

```
#include <functional>

class A
{
private:
    int value;

public:
    // Default constructor
    A()
    : value(0)
    { };

    // Constructor
    A(int value)
    : value(value)
    { };

    // Returns a lambda expression
    std::function<int()> get_value()
    {
        return [](){ return value; };
        // Gives error: "error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function"
    }
};
```

I know for this implementation it can be programmed much easier (leave away the lambda expression), but I think it is good to explain and understand the concept.

The question: how to use class member variables in class member lambda expressions? In other words: how do I capture 'this' within a lambda function in a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture `this` then you should capture `this`:

```
return [this](){ return value; };
```

However, this comes with the usual caveat that the `this` captured by the lambda can only be used as long as `this` is alive.

**PS**

> I know for this implementation it can be programmed much easier (leave away the lambda expression), [...]

If you want to have a callable that returns you the `value` of an `A` then I wouldn't know how to do it (easily) without using a lambda expression. I rather see the problem in your design. As mentioned above the caller needs to be cautious to only use the returned `std::function` as long as the `A` object is alive. There is a non-obvious dependency with the effect that your `A` can be easily used wrong:

```
auto f = A{}.get_value();
```

This creates a broken `std::function<int()>`. Frankly, your code is what I would call "encapsulation gone terribly wrong". Of course your code is just an example, but consider this example:

```
struct A { int value = 0; };

int main() {
    A a;
    auto f = [&](){ return a.value; };
}
```

Here the caller (ie the user of `A`) has the dependency (usability of `f` depends on lifetime of `a`) explicitly in their code.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer! So to be clear, the '&' in the `[&](){ return a.value; }` stands for the same as the 'this' in `[this](){ return value; }`?

Comment: @suitendaal no, `&` is short-hand for "capture everything by reference" see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for all the details, its a bit overwhelming, but if you scroll down to "Lambda capture" there are examples for capturing `this` or `&`.